# Linux Script Unexpected end of file error

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am new to shell scripting. I was trying to write a script to which is throwing an unexpected end of file error. I have check other solutions on stackoverflow, however I coul not solve the here. Any help would be appreciated. My script is

```
if [ "$(/etc/init.d/tomcat7 status)" == " * Tomcat servlet engine is not running." ]; then /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start; fi
```

As suggested I tried creating this in linux and now I get an error [:  * Tomcat servlet engine is not running.: unexpected operator

Comment: Did you create this script on the linux system or did you create it on Windows and then transferred the file?

Comment: This looks normal. Are you sure this is all of your script?

Comment: Yes this is all of the script. However as Joni said I created this on windows and then transferred it to linux.

Comment: `==` is not an operator for the `[` command. Either use a single `=` or use `[[ a == b ]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you created the file on Windows your original problem was most likely due to a mismatch of line-break characters. Windows encodes line-breaks as CR-LF, while Linux/Unix uses just LF and Mac OS just CR. You can fix that with e.g.

```
recode ibmpc..latin1 your.sh
```

Also you should specify the interpreter in the first line of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Your script should probably look somewhat like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(/etc/init.d/tomcat7 status)" == " * Tomcat servlet engine is not running." ]; then
  /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote the script on windows most probably the problem is the different encoding of line-end characters \r\n on windows while a single \n on linux.

Try using `dos2unix` on your script and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this looking at [[ :Unexpected operator in shell programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411048/unexpected-operator-in-shell-programming).

I had to run it as bash instead of sh.