# I can't use built-in bash commands when running a script using 'sh'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I execute my script `sh myscript.sh`  I get an error message which states that `[[:` is an 'unexpected operator', however when i run my script in a bash emulator (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php) it works and doesn't return this error. Furthermore, when i run the script using `sh` within the emulator it works and doesn't return the error even though on my server it would.

I've checked the link below and, from what i understand, i need to use the `bash` command. What is wrong with the `sh` command and how do i enable functions such as `[[:` to be executed?

NOTE: I am a student and therefore i can only run the bash terminal in school. So any help that will guarantee that this error will not be returned will be hugely appreciated.

[[ :Unexpected operator in shell programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411048/unexpected-operator-in-shell-programming)

Comment: What you use `sh` instead of `bash`, most `bash` extensions are disabled, including this one.

Comment: If your `sh` is a symbolic link to `bash`, read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode

Comment: What do you mean "I am a student and therefore I can only run the bash terminal"?  If you have access to a compiler, then you can build whatever shell you want!  Doing so is an excellent exercise.

Comment: K, i will do some research into this! Thanks! :)

Comment: Maybe also read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could think about it like this:
There are many "human languages" (French, Japanese, English, Hindi etc)

There are many different "shell languages" (sh, csh, tcsh, zsh, bash etc)
Think of `sh` and `bash` as languages, not commands.

The errors you are getting is because your computer is expecting you to talk to it in `sh`, but actually you are talking to it in `bash`. It is like giving a French document to a German translator....

So, to resolve this, you just need to inform your computer that your script is written in `bash`.

To do this, simply add this line to the very top of your script file:

**#!/bin/bash**

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer is to just use `bash myscript.sh`.  As has been mentioned below, the `[[` syntax is bash specific, and not supported by sh.

These are two separate shells, each with their own variation on the scripting language.  A vulgar analogy would be that bash is to sh, what c++ is to c.  Bash has more features, and some easier syntax, but they share a lot in common.

If you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your file, then it's a bash script.  You run this by entering `bash yourscript.sh` if it is not executable, or simply `./yourscript.sh` if it is.

If you have `#!/bin/sh`, then it's an sh script.  You run this by the same principles described above.

Comment: How do I move it to `#!/bin.bash`?

Comment: The top of a script MUST have a #! line, called 'shebang' or 'hashbang'. It tells the kernel what program to run your script with. I recommend `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/733901/58803). http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Scripts http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/

Comment: So within my script writer, i should have the first line as `#!/usr/bin/env bash`? [I use mcedit as my script writer]

Comment: The whole point of the `#!` line is that you *don't* have to invoke it by typing `sh yourscript`. Just type `./yourscript`, and the system will figure how to run it.

Comment: @pythontamer: Either `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash` should work. I prefer the latter. See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454).

Comment: Will this solve my problem? Just to be clear, i enter this on the very first line of my script writer cause wouldn't it be interpreted as a comment?

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein: Having a `#!` line is certainly a good idea, but it's not mandatory. If it's missing, you can still execute the script by typing `sh scriptname` or `bash scriptname` explicitly. (As for the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick, see my previous comment.)

Comment: @pythontamer: "*Will this solve my problem?*" -- Did you try it?

Comment: I've added this to my question: "NOTE: I am a student and therefore i can only run the bash terminal in school. So any help that will guarantee that this error will not be returned will be hugely appreciated." Sorry for the inconvenience this may cause.

Comment: @pythontamer: `bash` is a shell, not a terminal. If you want to run the `sh` shell rather than bash, you should be able to type `sh` at a bash prompt, or for a script put `#!/bin/sh` on the first line. If you mean that your current assignment requires you to use bash, that's a different story, but there's no reason being a student should prevent you from running a different shell.

Answer (score 2):

Many Linux distributions use a smaller, simpler shell implementation than Bash for their default `sh` binary. They do this for various reasons. If you need Bash, run `bash` explicitly.

Comment: So if i enter `bash myscript.sh` it will execute the code which contains the function `[[:`?

Answer (score 1):

`[[` is a **Bash** keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command.

See

- [Bash FAQ 31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)
- [Test and Conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals).

Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, it is recommended to use `[[` instead of `[`.