# unix shell script unexpected error

Tags: shell, unix

when I run the following script

```
#!/bin/sh
[ `whoami` == root ] || echo "must be run as root"
```

I get the following error

```
./test.sh: 2: [: root: unexpected operator
```

How can I avoid that error?

Comment: `[ \`whoami\` == "root" ] || echo "must be root"`

Answer (score 6):

While it might seem like the problem is not quoting the word `root`, your script does run without error on my machine, even without quoting it. So it seems your error depends on the shell implementation.

The problem is that `sh` is implemented by different shells in different environments. The posix `sh` command doesn't support `==` (only `=`), and I think that's the error you're experiencing. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3411105/1230403).

Try changing the first line to `#!/bin/bash` to see if this is the case on your machine.

Comment: @draca, since you're using `[` not `[[`, you want to "quote all the things", so `[ "$(whoami)" = root ]`

Comment: @draca, can you please accept the answer if it's correct? thanks

Comment: Had this issue in a dockerfile, worked just fine on Alpine, ubuntu on the other hand did not like it! Thanks for the answer ;)