# Shell not evaluating multiple conditions in IF statement

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I want to sort files into folders based on two conditions, but it won't evaluate both conditions. The conditions are based on values read in from a text file (index.txt) that correspond to the particular subject, and values are coded as 0 or 1

```
Subid   DX    SEX
XXXX    0      0
YYYY    1      0
```

the code is as follows

```
    #!/bin/sh 
    d=XXXX
    dx=$(awk '{if($1=='$d'){print $2}}' index.txt)
    sex=$(awk '{if($1=='$d'){print $3}}' index.txt)
    if [ "$dx" == "0" ] && [ "$sex" == "0" ];then
     commands
    fi
```

I have tried using double brackets `[[ <condition 1> ]] && [[ <condition 2> ]];`, collapsing brackets `if [ <condition1> && <condition2> ];`, parentheses, and using `-eq` instead of `==`, but they still are not evaluating and no errors are being printed. What am I missing?

Comment: Where are `$x` and `$y` set? As you show it, they're going to be the empty string.

Comment: Use `=`, not `==`, with `[ ... ]`.

Comment: Note that the shell *is* evaluating the first condition; it's just finding that `""` (because `x` is undefined) does not equal `"0"`, and so `&&` prevents the second condition from being evaluated.

Comment: edited to show the variables. Unfortunately using a single `=` didn't do it

Comment: Running your code with the file you provided (index.txt), your $dx and $sex variables are empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most useful tricks when debugging a shell script is `set -x` (or running the entire script with `sh -x`). This makes the shell print the equivalent of each command as it executes them, so you can get a better idea what's actually happening and whether it matches what you expect. Let's try it on your script:

```
$ sh -x reader.sh
+ d=XXXX
++ awk '{if($1==XXXX){print $2}}' index.txt
+ dx=
++ awk '{if($1==XXXX){print $3}}' index.txt
+ sex=
+ '[' '' == 0 ']'
```

Note that it set both `dx` and `sex` to the empty string. And if you look at the awk script that's being executed, you can see why: `XXXX` doesn't have double-quotes around it, so awk is treating it as a variable name, rather than a literal string to match against.

You could add double-quotes, but that's not really the best way to do it; sticking literal strings into executable code (an awk script in this case) risks parts of the strings being mistaken for executable code, which can have really weird/bad consequences. The better way to do this sort of thing is to pass the data around *as data*, by using awk's `-v` option to set a variable, and then using that. Something like:

```
$ awk -v d="XXXX" '{if($1==d){print $2}}' index.txt
0
```

Hey, it printed the right thing! So here's a version of your script using that:

```
#!/bin/sh
d=XXXX
dx=$(awk -v d="$d" '{if($1==d){print $2}}' index.txt)
sex=$(awk -v d="$d" '{if($1==d){print $3}}' index.txt)
if [ "$dx" = "0" ] && [ "$sex" = "0" ];then
    commands
fi
```

Note that the awk variable named `d` has no intrinsic connection to the shell variable named `d`; the `-v d="$d"` bit copies the shell variable into the same-named awk variable. Also, I switched the `==` to just `=` in the comparison, since that's the standard string-equal operator inside `[ ]`. bash allows `==` as a synonym, but not all shells do this; if you're writing specifically for bash, you should use a specific bash shebang line (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) rather than `#!/bin/sh`.

(Actually, I'd recommend using a bash shebang, because if you're not clear on what's standard shell syntax and what's a bash extension, you probably aren't writing portably anyway, so explicitly requesting bash is safer. And if you're doing that, you might as well switch to `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`, because it avoids many of the syntactic oddities that `[ ]` expressions suffer from.)

Comment: It was reading in my awk syntax fine but I ran sh -x and saw that windows added those invisible carriages to the lines in index and thats why. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your conditions but with your variables set with awk.

Try the following to set your variables:

```
#!/bin/sh
d=XXXX
dx=$(awk '{if ($1 ~ /'$d'/) print $3}' index.txt)
sex=$(awk '{if ($1 ~ /'$d'/) print $3}' index.txt)
if [ "$dx" = "0" ] && [ "$sex" = "0" ];then
echo "works"
fi
```

Comment: Using `==` instead of `=` limits the implements of `/bin/sh` that this code will work with. [The POSIX `test` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) only defines `=`, and implementations that do not support `==` (always report an error and return false when it's used) are not uncommon. See [`[`: Unexpected operator in shell programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411048).

Comment: (To clarify what I mean by "not uncommon" -- think "installed out-of-the-box on Ubuntu").

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy, corrected my answer to be POSIX compliant.