# Bash Linux - call function in a if statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have probably some nooby question

how can I call a defined function in a if statement in bash?

Have a look on my example:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
Variable_A=xyz

function_x() {

echo "hello everyone"
}

#here I want to define a if statement after the function
if Variable_A == working;then
function_x()

#here I have a while for the parameters in bash example:
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
key="$1"
    case $key in
        -s|--status)
        Variable_A="$2"
        shift
        shift
        ;;
    esac
done
```

so the idea is when I run the script let's call it test.sh it runs the script exp in bash:

```
./test.sh working
```

I am not sure how to create something like this, maybe some of you can help me out on this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` should look like:

```
#here I want to define a if statement after the function
if [ "$Variable_A" = "working" ]
then
  function_x
fi
```

You need to end every if statement with `fi` and functions are called without `()`.
https://www.thegeekdiary.com/bash-if-loop-examples-if-then-fi-if-then-elif-fi-if-then-else-fi/

Another important note on `if` statements.  You need a space before and after `[` or `]`.

Your `if` logic should also be after the script parms are read and `Variable_A` is set.

Comment: Note that it should be `==` in the condition.

Comment: @vicraj who told you that?

Comment: For checking string equality between variables, you should use `==`, and for integers, you should use `-eq`, as explained in this [Unix tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-basic-operators.htm).

Comment: @vicraj Actually I was told the right syntax is to use a single = just a few days ago here in SO, although both work.

Comment: OK, I didn't know. Since `==` is common to almost all programming languages, I prefer to continue using it anyway, since it is much more readable IMHO.

Comment: More thoroughly discussed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449543/bash-equality-operators-eq) for those interested.

Comment: Single `=` is the portable one, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: @vicraj, ...if you want an example of a SO question / third-party bug caused by someone using the `==` (not-really-an-)operator instead of `=`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411048/unexpected-operator-in-shell-programming

Comment: @vicraj == is not "common to almost all programming languages".

Comment: Ok, I get the point, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: thx, this worked :) awsome ! :)